# Node stuck with error " Irmin_pack__Pack.File(Index)(K).Make(V).Invalid_read "

Tags: node, docker

My node crashed and is outputing these errors:

```
| Sep 29 11:15:24 - validator.peer: Worker crashed [node_peer_validator]:                                                                            
| Sep 29 11:15:24 - validator.peer: Irmin_pack__Pack.File(Index)(K).Make(V).Invalid_read                                                             
| Sep 29 11:15:25 - validator.block: Validation of block BMLXeNspcWdbZtx4WH29b67feuZEbnV5W37dCY1Njozgkos8Z39 failed 
| Sep 29 11:15:25 - validator.block: Request pushed on 2020-09-29T11:15:24-00:00, treated in 543ms,completed in 531ms ,
| Sep 29 11:15:25 - validator.block: Irmin_pack__Pack.File(Index)(K).Make(V).Invalid_read
| Sep 29 11:15:25 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: unexpected error while fetching headers
```

I'm running it with docker and I'm not sure how to fix that. Is it possible to reject a block from the docker container?
Thanks a lot and have a good day

Comment: Check `dmesg` for any disk-related issues. Looks like your database got corrupted due to bad read/write. You might want to just blow it away and import a recent snapshot. That'll be the safest thing to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yep probably that